# How to make AutoFac use same instance of nested dependency per top-level object? (SignalR dependency injection per hub)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, signalr, autofac, signalr-hub

I am trying to set up my AutoFac registration in such a way that this test passes:

```
[Test]
public void Autofac_registration_test()
{
    // Given
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    RegisterServices(builder);
    var container = builder.Build();

    // When
    var firstHub = container.Resolve<Hub>();
    var secondHub = container.Resolve<Hub>();

    // Then
    firstHub.Should().NotBe(secondHub);
    firstHub.FooRepo.Context.Should().Be(firstHub.BarRepo.Context);
    firstHub.FooRepo.Context.Should().NotBe(secondHub.FooRepo.Context);
}
```

i.e. I want to use the same `Context` object all the way down within a single `Hub`, but use a different one when a new `Hub` is created.

`RegisterServices` is currently just:

```
private void RegisterServices(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RegisterType<MyHub>();
    builder.RegisterType<FooRepo>();
    builder.RegisterType<BarRepo>();
    builder.RegisterType<Context>(); // How should I scope this?
}
```

Which fails at `firstHub.FooRepo.Context.Should().Be(firstHub.BarRepo.Context);` because `Context` is transiently scoped.

But scoping context per lifetime also fails, this time at `firstHub.FooRepo.Context.Should().NotBe(secondHub.FooRepo.Context);`.

It feels like this is a reasonable thing to want to do, so am I missing anything obvious out-of-the-box here?
Or will I have to do something manual to track `Hub` creation?

(For context, this is for a [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) app. Hubs are created per SignalR request, so this was an attempt to match the unit-of-work lifetime of an HTTP request in normal webby situations).

Comment: Also, I am not totally married to AutoFac. If there is another dependency injection framework that handles this gracefully that would be fine too!

Comment: Partial answer: It's probably going to involve named lifetime scopes. This answer may have enough info to get you going: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16820778/540663

Comment: What you are looking for is the per-object-graph lifestyle, which is something not many containers support. AFAIK Autofac doesn't either. The usual way to handle this is by starting a new lifetime scope A @JimBolla said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @Steven said in his comment was correct, I needed a per-object-graph lifestyle.

[Castle.Windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx) supports this, so I swicthed to using that for my dependency injection instead of AutoFac. The registration now looks like:

```
container.Register(Component.For<Hub>().LifestyleTransient());
container.Register(Component.For<FooRepo>().LifestyleTransient());
container.Register(Component.For<BarRepo>().LifestyleTransient());
container.Register(Component.For<Context>().LifestyleBoundTo<Hub>()); // Important bit
```

For more information, see: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.LifeStyles.ashx?HL=scope#Bound_8