# Resolve parameters according to the parent tree that triggered the resolve?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, dryioc

I have code similar to this:

```
class A: IA { ... }
class B: IB {
    public B(IA a, ...) { ... }
    ...
}
class C1 {
    public C1(IA a, IB b, ...) { ... }
}
class C2 {
    public C2(IA a, IB b, ...) { ... }
}
```

What I want is only two instances of A -- one to go with C1 and one to go with C2. I want two instances of B. The instance of B passed to C1 should get the same instance of A created for C1. C2 and his parameters should have a different instance of A. **How can I configure this scenario in Autofac?** It looked like the Owned instance lifetime feature was supposed to handle this, but the posted example was only one layer deep, not two.

My real situation is much more complex. I have a dozen inheritors of IB and a half dozen C defs that take various combinations of the IB inheritors. I wanted to avoid using the named instances because that would bloat my bootstrapper significantly and make it difficult to maintain.

Secondary question: does DryIoc support this? I could be talked into switching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for something called "instance per graph" lifetime scope. It is not supported natively by autofac. If you're not stuck with autofac you can use [Castle Windsor as explained in this related/duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25670739/how-to-make-autofac-use-same-instance-of-nested-dependency-per-top-level-object).

If you're looking for a solution with autofac itself, you can implement it with `InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope` or `InstancePerLifetimeScope`.

Here's how you configure your container

```
private IContainer Build()
{
    ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterType<A>().As<IA>().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("SomeTag");
    builder.RegisterType<B>().As<IB>().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("SomeTag");
    builder.RegisterType<C1>();

    return builder.Build();
}
```

Here's how you use it

```
[Test]
public void PerGraphLifeStyle()
{
    var container = Build();

    C1 c1;
    C1 c2;
    using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope("SomeTag"))
    {
        c1 = scope.Resolve<C1>();
        Assert.AreSame(c1.A, c1.B.A);
    }

    using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope("SomeTag"))
    {
        c2 = scope.Resolve<C1>();
        Assert.AreSame(c1.A, c1.B.A);
    }

    Assert.AreNotSame(c1.A, c2.A);
}
```

Dummy classes I created for testing are below

```
internal interface IA
{
}

class A : IA
{

}

internal interface IB
{
    IA A { get; set; }
}

class B : IB
{
    public B(IA a)
    {
        A = a;
    }

    public IA A { get; set; }
}
class C1
{
    public IA A { get; set; }
    public IB B { get; set; }

    public C1(IA a, IB b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent code demonstration. I'll have to think on this a little farther as I don't actually call `Resolve` on any of my C objects. They're all a ways down the chain. I only resolve a couple of high level objects out of my container and the rest (600ish) are filled in through factories and construction of necessary constructor dependencies.

Comment: @Brannon I know it is a pain if you don't call `Resolve` yourself for these objects. One way is to hide these code inside the factory class. So you call `factory.CreateC1()` factory will encapsulate a container and create LifetimeScope and call resolve for you.

Comment: Autofac directly supports "instance-per-graph" with `InstancePerOwned` lifetime (very similar to how DryIoc does it):

`c.RegisterType<A>().InstancePerOwned<C>(); // A is reused in C`

Comment: @dadhi Is it same as the instance per graph? It forces us to use `Owned<T>` type in our entity right? Which means we're tightly coupled to our IOC container --which is a bad thing. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: There are pros and cons to the approach, but that's another thing:

pros: Using Owned easily provides IDispose for you.

cons: Yes, you need to reference container to use Owned wrapper.
DryIoc supports this without wrapper, but to be able to Dispose - you still need `ResolutionScoped<T>`.

Comment: __Update:__ Now DryIoc rc1 is capable to inject `IDisposable scope` so you can control scope disposal without additional wrappers.

Answer (score 4):

In [DryIoc](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc) (which is mine) it may be directly achieved using [Reuse.InResolutionScopeOf](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/ReuseAndScopes#markdown-header-reuseinresolutionscopeof):

```
container.Register<C1>(setup: Setup.With(openResolutionScope: true), serviceKey: Some.Blah);
container.Register<C2>(setup: Setup.With(openResolutionScope: true), serviceKey: Some.Blah);

container.Register<IA, A>(reuse: Reuse.InResolutionScopeOf(serviceKey: Some.Blah));
```

That's it. `openResolutionScope: true` creates scope in object graph.`serviceKey` is required to identify/find the scope in graph. For instance if `C1` and `C2` would implement same interface `IC` then no need in service key. You just say `Reuse.InResolutionScopeOf<IC>()` and it will be one `IA` for each `IC` object in graph.

Comment: If you're the author of DryIoc, you need to disclose it. Otherwise folks here would consider this as a spam or something. Thanks.